# How do I use the information passed to a pointer in one function, and output it in another?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void enterRents(int *rent, int size)
{

    cout << endl;
    int i = 0;
    int rentArray[7];

    for (size; size < 7; size++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Rent Amount " << size + 1 << endl;
        cin >> rentArray[i];
        rent = &rentArray[i];
        i++;

    }
}


void displayRents(int *rent, int size)
{
    cout << "Rents:" << endl;
    size = 7;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "$" << *(rent + i);
        cout << endl;
    }


}
```

I want to be able to take the numbers I put into the rentArray in function enterRents and just output them all in function displayRents. But on the line "  cout << "$" << *(rent + i);" it gives me an exception thrown: read access violation. Im unsure what that means. I thought I had my code setup properly.

Comment: Well. Think about this. You pass the pointer `rent`. Then in the function you simply need to `cin >> amount;` and then since `[..]` functions as a dereference of a pointer, you can simply use `rent[i] = amount;` to update the value at the memory address `rent + 1`. (where `rent[i]` == `*(rent + i)`)

Comment: What is the [..] that you reference?

Comment: Just the normal array index notation, e.g. `int array[10];` and then `array[2] = 5;` The `[..]` provides the short form to access the value at an offset from `array`. That is why `array[2]` is equivalent to `*(array + 2)` and why `array[0]` which is `*(array + 0)` can simply use `*array`..

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in the code you've shown.

- `int rentArray[7];` is a local variable that will be destroyed when the function returns. Any pointers you set to point into that variable will be invalid when the function returns and dereferencing them will cause Undefined Behavior.
- `for (size; size < 7; size++)` doesn't make sense. `size` is supplied by the calling function and shouldn't be changed. Also, `size` doesn't do anything so `size < 7` is going to be `false` if `7` is supplied by the calling function.
- If `cin >> rentArray[i];` fails, it'll leave `rentArray[i]` uninitialized and reading it later will also cause undefined behaviour.

Here's how it could be done instead:

```
#include <cstddef>  // std::size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   // std::size

// return the number of successfully extracted rents:
size_t enterRents(int* rent, const size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter Rent Amount " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        if(!(std::cin >> rent[i])) return i;  // check that extraction succeeded
    }
    return size;
}

void displayRents(const int* rent, const size_t size) {
    std::cout << "Rents:\n";
 
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << "$" << rent[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int rentArray[7];

    size_t size = enterRents(rentArray, std::size(rentArray));

    std::cout << "You entered " << size << " rent(s).\n";

    displayRents(rentArray, size);
}
```

There is however a container in the standard library that would be perfect for this: `std::vector`. If rewritten to use that instead:

```
#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   // std::vector

void enterRents(std::vector<int>& rent, const size_t max_rents) {
    int temp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < max_rents; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter Rent Amount " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        if(!(std::cin >> temp)) return;
        rent.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void displayRents(const std::vector<int>& rent) {
    std::cout << "Rents:\n";
 
    for(int value : rent) {
        std::cout << "$" << value << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> rentArray;

    enterRents(rentArray, 7);

    std::cout << "You entered " << rentArray.size() << " rent(s).\n";

    displayRents(rentArray);
}
```

Or let `enterRents` create the `std::vector<int>` and return it by value:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> enterRents(const size_t max_rents) {
    std::vector<int> rent;
    rent.reserve(max_rents);
    int temp;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < max_rents; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter Rent Amount " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        if(!(std::cin >> temp)) break;
        rent.push_back(temp);
    }
    return rent;
}

void displayRents(const std::vector<int>& rent) {
    std::cout << "Rents:\n";
 
    for(int value : rent) {
        std::cout << "$" << value << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> rentArray = enterRents(7);

    std::cout << "You entered " << rentArray.size() << " rent(s).\n";

    displayRents(rentArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if we can get you sorted out. After looking through your functions, it seems you are confused about how to handle declaring storage for `rent` outside of your functions and being able to pass a pointer to `rent` as a parameter and update the values for each of the elements of `rent` within the function and have the changes available back in the calling function.

Think about what you need as far as your code logic goes. You need:

1. A constant that defines how many elements there are in `rent`,
2. You need the array of integer values for `rent`, and finally
3. You need a counter that holds the number of rents entered by the user (the user could enter less than all you request)

Now on to storage for `rent`. While you should use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and pass a reference to the vector (this is C++ after all), there is educational value in understanding handling POA (plain old array) types and pointers. I suspect that is what you are working on.

Before you can start assigning values, you must have valid storage to put them in. When you declare an array, you create storage for that array on your program (or function) stack. The storage is valid for the life of that function and you are free to pass a pointer to that array and have the elements filled in as many functions as you like. If you have declared your array in `main()`, the storage will remain valid for the life of the program (until return from `main()`).

Your counter can be declared as a simple integer in `main()` and it too has storage reserved on the program stack. Similarly, you can pass a pointer to your counter to your `enterRents()` function and update the value at the address for the original variable within the function. For example, in your case you can write a short `main()` that does:

```
#define ARRSZ 7
...
int main (void) {
    
    int rent[ARRSZ],                    /* array of rents */
        size = 0;                       /* number of rents entered */
    
    enterRents (rent, &size);           /* get the rents */
    ...
```

There you declare your array and your counter `size` and pass a pointer to the first element in `rent` and a pointer to `size` as parameters to `enterRents()`. (on access an array is converted to a pointer to the first element automatically)

So now if for each successful value entered in `enterRents()`, the value stored at the address for `size` is updated by `1`, you have a way to validate how many rents were entered so you can output the rents entered by the user -- even if less than `ARRSZ` rents were entered. Your complete `main()` would be:

```
int main (void) {
    
    int rent[ARRSZ],                    /* array of rents */
        size = 0;                       /* numer of rents entered */
    
    enterRents (rent, &size);           /* get the rents */
    if (size > 0)                       /* validate at least 1 rent entered */
        displayRents (rent, size);      /* display rents */
    else    /* otherwise none entered */
        std::cerr << "No rents entered.\n";
}
```

(**note:** you do NOT invoke undefined behavior if the user enters less than `ARRSZ` rents and terminates input by generating a manual `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>))

Now looking at `enterRents()`, you will need to loop continually until the user enters `ARRSZ` rents OR an unrecoverable stream error occurs or the user generates a manual `EOF`. You validate EVERY input by checking the stream state following the input. See [std::basic_istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (*Member Functions*) In the event the user enters `"cow"` instead of a valid integer, you handle that case by checking for `std::cin.fail()` and you need to `.clear()` the stream error and then empty all offending characters from `stdin` before attempting the next input. (you do that with `.ignore()`)

Your `enterRents()` could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#define ARRSZ 7

void enterRents(int *rent, int *size)
{
    std::cout << "Enter rents for " << ARRSZ << " properties\n\n";
    
    while (*size < ARRSZ)       /* loop until ARRSZ rents entered or EOF or error */
    {
        int amount;                     /* temporary int to store input */
        std::cout << "Property " << *size + 1 << " Rent Amount: ";
        if (std::cin >> amount) {       /* read input / validate */
            rent[*size] = amount;       /* store amount at *size offset in rent */
            (*size)++;                  /* increment value at address */
        }
        /* check unrecoverable error or manual EOF */
        else if (std::cin.bad() || std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cerr << "\nstream error or manual EOF\n";
            return;
        }
        /* check if non-integer input given */
        else if (std::cin.fail()) {
            char badinput[1024];
            std::cin.clear();       /* clear stream error */
            if (std::cin >> badinput)
                std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input '" << badinput << "'\n";
            /* discard offending characters left in stdin */
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Finally your `displayRents()` simply needs to take the array as a parameter and a copy of `size` is fine (you won't be updating the value at that address within the display function)

```
void displayRents(int *rent, int size)
{
    std::cout << "\nRents:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << "$" << rent[i] << '\n';
}
```

Putting it altogether you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#define ARRSZ 7

void enterRents(int *rent, int *size)
{
    std::cout << "Enter rents for " << ARRSZ << " properties\n\n";
    
    while (*size < ARRSZ)       /* loop until ARRSZ rents entered or EOF or error */
    {
        int amount;                     /* temporary int to store input */
        std::cout << "Property " << *size + 1 << " Rent Amount: ";
        if (std::cin >> amount) {       /* read input / validate */
            rent[*size] = amount;       /* store amount at *size offset in rent */
            (*size)++;                  /* increment value at address */
        }
        /* check unrecoverable error or manual EOF */
        else if (std::cin.bad() || std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cerr << "\nstream error or manual EOF\n";
            return;
        }
        /* check if non-integer input given */
        else if (std::cin.fail()) {
            char badinput[1024];
            std::cin.clear();       /* clear stream error */
            if (std::cin >> badinput)
                std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input '" << badinput << "'\n";
            /* discard offending characters left in stdin */
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}


void displayRents(int *rent, int size)
{
    std::cout << "\nRents:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << "$" << rent[i] << '\n';
}

int main (void) {
    
    int rent[ARRSZ],                    /* array of rents */
        size = 0;                       /* number of rents entered */
    
    enterRents (rent, &size);           /* get the rents */
    if (size > 0)                       /* validate at least 1 rent entered */
        displayRents (rent, size);      /* display rents */
    else    /* otherwise none entered */
        std::cerr << "No rents entered.\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rents
Enter rents for 7 properties

Property 1 Rent Amount: 585
Property 2 Rent Amount: 640
Property 3 Rent Amount: 935
Property 4 Rent Amount: 400
Property 5 Rent Amount: 655
Property 6 Rent Amount: 495
Property 7 Rent Amount: 700

Rents:
$585
$640
$935
$400
$655
$495
$700
```

Or in the case of less than all being entered:

```
$ ./bin/rents
Enter rents for 7 properties

Property 1 Rent Amount: 585
Property 2 Rent Amount: 640
Property 3 Rent Amount: Mickey Mouse
error: invalid integer input 'Mickey'
Property 3 Rent Amount: 935
Property 4 Rent Amount:
stream error or manual EOF

Rents:
$585
$640
$935
```

Or in the case of `EOF` before any rent entered:

```
$ ./bin/rents
Enter rents for 7 properties

Property 1 Rent Amount:
stream error or manual EOF
No rents entered.
```

The key is to ***validate, validate, validate*** so that no matter what the crazy user inputs -- your program handles it gracefully. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.